# How to reproduce my loop in bash with powershell?

Tags: bash, powershell, loops, csv, while-loop

I've this type of file :

```
foo/foo,foo2/foo2,foo3/foo3
```

And I Would like this output :

```
foo/foo
foo1/foo1
foo2/foo2
```

With bash I'm able to do that (even if I sure that is not the cleanest way, but it works ) :

```
#!/bin/bash

numdel=3

while IFS="," read line
do
        for i in $(seq 1 $numdel)
        do
                echo $line | cut -d',' -f$i

        done
done < CSV.csv
```

The output is :

```
foo/foo
foo1/foo1
foo2/foo2
```

I try to reproduce the same but in powershell and I can't... There is someone to show me how to do that with powershell ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$files = 'foo/foo,foo2/foo2,foo3/foo3'

$files.split(',')
```

[image]

So for input from a file you would need to use

```
$files = Get-Content $filePath
```

If you had in excess of one file you would need to create an object having them and then loop through them:

```
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\some\target\path' -filter '*.csv'

ForEach ($item in $items) {

 $files = Get-Content -Path $item.FullName
 $output = $files.split(',')

 return $output

}
```

You could then redirect that output to a file using

```
> - create a new file
```

```
>> - append to a file
```

Or using

```
Set-Content
```

Comment: I renamed `$input` to `$files` because `$input` is [an automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#input), using it might get you into trouble :)